# searching and extracting particular data from json using python

Tags: python, json, api, data-science, rest

I am fetching data using API, I want to perform operation to get total number of transaction amount made by each user and also the name of city
the api link is :

```
url = "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/transactions/search?txnType=debit&page=1"
data = requests.get(url)
parsed = json.loads(data)
```

[fetched data from api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsuZb.png)

Comment: Please post the raw data instead of posting the image of data, makes it easier for folks to read your data and help you.

Comment: `requests.get()` returns '`Response`' type, not json string.  
You should pass `data.json()` instead of just `data` to `json.loads()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach to get what you want in a list of tuples having (name, amount, location)

```
url = "https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/transactions/search?txnType=debit&page=1"
data = requests.get(url)
parsed = json.loads(data.content)

samples = []
for item in parsed['data']:
    samples.append((item['userName'], item['amount'], item['location']['city']))
print(samples)
```

Comment: Please use `data.json` instead of using direct `json.loads` on `data`. `data` is Respone object which has a `json` method for json serialization.